# Number System Divisibility by 7

Tags: divisibility, number-systems

X is a number formed by writing 9 for 99 times. What will be the remainder of this number when divided by 7?

Comment: So you're looking at $10^n -1 \mod{7}$. Maybe you can give some values for $n$ and see if you find a pattern.

Comment: Is there anything you have already tried? I can think of two methods which enable me to do this in my head, but just telling you what they are won't help you much in solving similar problems - trying it yourself will help.

Comment: Are you familiar with Fermat's little theorem?

Answer (score 1):

$X= 10^{99} - 1 = 10^{3 \times 33} - 1$.

Now $10^3 = 1000 = -1$ modulo $7$.

So $X=(-1)^{33} - 1 = - 1 - 1 = 5$ modulo $7$.

Comment: Easier: $\bmod 7\!:\,\ 10^{\large 3}\equiv 3^{\large 3}\equiv 3\cdot 2 \equiv -1\ \ $